# max value if no values are none - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I would like to return a item in a list if certain conditions are met. One condition is that my the Project is `"Project A"`, but the other is that `t[1]` is not `None` for all sublists that contain `"Project A"`. The code I have works, but it seems inefficient. How can I combine this down?

```
mylist = [(1, None, "Project A"), (2, 3, "Project A"), (3, 6, "Project B")]

try:
    if None not in [t[1] for t in mylist if t[2] == "Project A"]:
        print max(t for t in mylist if t[2] == "Project A" and t[1] is not None)
    else:
        print "no match"
except ValueError:
    print "no match"
```

Comment: If your code works, submit it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for suggestions on improvements instead.

Comment: @ILostMySpoon: the question is perfectly on-topic here, and this is just a small snippet. This is not suitable for CR therefor. Can you please review the CR [on-topic help information](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before recommending people repost there?

Comment: @MartijnPieters *"..this is just a small snippet. This is not suitable for CR therefore"* — as far as I can tell the question is on topic on both sites. Where did you read about excluding  "small snippets"?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: It is a simplified example, not real project code; from [their helpcenter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): *Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?* But the most important reason not to migrate is: it is not off-topic *here*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tmp = [x for x in mylist if x[2] == "Project A"]
if tmp and None not in zip(*tmp)[1]:
    print max(tmp)
else:
    print "no match"
```

Comment: Could you also explain your solution with a copule of sentences?

Comment: @Magnilex I think it's pretty straight-forward. What part is unclear?

Comment: It is not for me, but your answer ended up in a review queue for potentially low quality question, hence my comment. Remember, even if it is trivial, a small explanation makes the answer better.

Comment: @Magnilex Self-explaining code is even better, and I believe mine is. But if someone who is actually interested expresses trouble understanding it, I'll explain.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to validate all matching entries anyway, your best option is to use a straight-up `for` loop; break out when the `None` condition isn't met:

```
found = None
for entry in mylist:
    if entry[2] == 'Project A':
        if entry[1] is None:
            print 'No match'
            break
        if not found or entry > found:
            found = entry
else:
    # only executed when there was no break!
    print found or 'No match'
```

The `else` branch of a `for` loop is executed only when the `for` loop completed iterating. That will only happen if there were any `Project A` entries were found where `t[1]` was set to `None`.

Since there is still the possibility that there are 0 entries that match the project name, `found` is set to `None` first; it is `None` still by the time you reach the `else` block the loop if no entries were there to be matched.

Demo, turning the *found `None`* case into an exception to show the difference:

```
>>> def find_max_project(projects, target):
...     found = None
...     for entry in projects:
...         if entry[2] == target:
...             if entry[1] is None:
...                 raise ValueError('no match')
...             if not found or entry > found:
...                 found = entry
...     else:
...         return found
... 

>>> find_max_project([(1, None, "Project A"), (2, 3, "Project A"), (3, 6, "Project B")], 'Project A')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in find_max_project
ValueError: 'no match'
>>> find_max_project([(1, 4, "Project A"), (2, 3, "Project A"), (3, 6, "Project B")], 'Project A')
(2, 3, 'Project A')
>>> find_max_project([(1, 2, "Project A"), (1, 3, "Project A")], 'Project A')
(1, 3, 'Project A')
>>> find_max_project([(1, 2, "Project B"), (1, 3, "Project B")], 'Project A')
>>> find_max_project([(1, 2, "Project B"), (1, 3, "Project B")], 'Project A') is None
True
```

Note that in this version we don't even really need to put the final line in an `else` block anymore, as using an exception ends the function now.

Comment: You should break if it *is* None. Also, prints the wrong item for input `[(1, 2, "Project A"), (1, 3, "Project A")]`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: ah, indeed; got my logic inverted. I also adjusted to take into account *both* values.

Comment: You could also get rid of max_value and just say `if not found or entry > found: found = entry`

Comment: @StefanPochmann: perhaps; it indeed doesn't make much sense here to keep that a separate variable now.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter and return the max, if there are  any None's with `"Project A"` you should not return straight away that there is no match:

```
 def filtered(l,proj):
    filt = []
    for t in l:
        if t[2] == proj:
            if t[1] is None:
                return "No match"
            filt.append(t)
    return max(filt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the simple `for` loop of Martijn but just for discussion you could use `key` parameter to make a `None` value be the max, if it exists, else return the maximum of the entries:

```
try:
    result = max((t for t in mylist if t[2] == "Project A"),
                 key=lambda x: (x[1] is None, x))
    print 'no match' if result[1] == None else result
except ValueError:
    print 'no match'
```

If you are guaranteed that `Project A` is in the list then you can get rid of the try block.

Comment: You could also use `key=lambda x: (x[1] is None, x)`.

Comment: @achampion can you explain your use of `lamba`. Not very familiar with this.

Comment: Take a look at `key` parameter to `max`, it takes a function that is passed each item and the result is used to make the comparison. `lambda` is just an anonymous function that takes `x` and returns the value used to compare. And I really like @Stefan's solution and have updated to it. This solution ensures that if there is a `None` in the list it is returned as the max, else the maximum is returned.